# What would be the mathematical features of a theory of everything?

Tags: theory-of-everything

GR and QFT are both axiomatic systems, right? If their axioms are logically independent, and a number of them are absolutely true in describing the universe, i.e. non-removable from a TOE, is there anyway to reduce the number of axioms? Is the dream of having a few axioms describing everything in the universe mathematically possible? Or am I confused about the whole nature of theories and axiomatic systems?

Edit: I guess this question has one [purely mathematical aspect](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204160/the-minimum-number-of-independent-axioms-of-a-theory) and one physical aspect. To focus on the physical aspect now, I concede that it's quite possible that zero of those axioms are true, which makes the question irrelevant. However, just the way that Newton's laws of motion can be derived from GR as estimations in many situations, I assume GR and QFT should be derivable as estimations from TOE. I don't know what implications this could have on the number of axioms in TOE...

Comment: Are you sure that "a number of them are absolutely true in describing the universe"? How do you verify such a thing?

Comment: Of course not. I'm saying that if the number of the true axioms is N and they are logically independent, is it possible for TOE to have less than N axioms?

Comment: Alright, let's back up a bit. What does it mean for an axiom to be "true"?

Comment: I think I get it: If GR depends on A, B and C being true. And QM depends on X, Y and Z being true, can a ToE depend on < 6 things? (obvs none of A,B,C,X,Y,Z are equivalent).

Comment: @OscarBravo You have stated the essence of the question. Notice how you have _not_ stated or otherwise assumed that A, B, C, X, Y, or Z are "absolutely true" and/or "non-removable from a TOE". Those are precisely the parts of the question that I take issue with, the rest is valid.

Comment: *Is the dream of having a few axioms describing everything in the universe mathematically possible?* This is impossible to answer.  The only way you could say "yes" would be to *have* such a (proven by experiment) theory and we don't.  But not having a proven theory does not make the answer no, just "don't know".

Comment: Isn’t the answer 42?

Comment: If you are 420-friendly, you may summarize yourself in 42?